# Apple Mail message -- remote content loaded through a VPN configuration

Tags: macos, mail.app, vpn

Remote content was loaded through your VPN configuration. This message appears above Gmail and iCloud Apple Mail messages. I don't use a VPN application. Apple explains that you can configure VPN Settings on macOS and iOS devices if you are enrolled in an MDM (Mobile Device Management) Solution. This is my iPhone and I have never installed an MDM solution or app.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to check Settings > Mail > Privacy Protection.

"When fully enabled, Mail Privacy Protection hides your IP address and downloads remote content privately when you receive a message."
https://www.makeuseof.com/mail-privacy-protection-explained-macos-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Mdm isn’t an app you would put on. It’s a policy your employer would likely put on. It can be part of Microsoft 365 /Azure or Google Workspace to name a couple. There are many companies that “manage” security on employee devices without your explicit permission. If you logged into a company account on your personal device your device can be MDM ‘d (Mobile Device Management). Mdm is used to manage devices so the company can control devices off of their property, remote usage. They use a vpn to make all communication (or the specific requested in setup of their policy) go through a manager and controlled vpn “tunnel” Go to settings-general-vpn/managed devices and go through headings. You should be able to reject device management from there. Also you will see if you are MDM’d with its accompanying vpn.  Be thankful it’s an apple because android doesn’t offer the mdm disable and you’re at the mercy of the policy holder ( again likely your employer). I went through this the hard way. This mdm/vpn policy can be highly intrusive on your device and your network. I have spent several years and many courses ( comp Tia plus and white hat hacking and am a Google admin) to fully understand the complexities of remote management and it’s abilities.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/334001)